# How to format a date in single line in JavaScript without using any library

Tags: javascript

How can I convert a day like `2020-05-01` to `5/1/2020` in one line.

I tried this but I wasn't able to remove the zero's nor I could arrange them in correct order.

`('2020-05-01').split('-').reverse().join('/')`

Comment: `'2020-05-01'.split('-').reduceRight((arr, str) => arr.concat(Number(str)), []).join('/')`

Comment: or with "unary plus" operator ... `'2020-05-01'.split('-').reduceRight((arr, str) => arr.concat(+str), []).join('/')`

Comment: Why the single line requirement?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.map` to iterate and `Number` to convert:

```js
console.log(
  ('2020-05-01')
    .split('-')
    .map(Number) // add this
    .reverse()
    .join('/')
);
```

Comment: is there any way to convert 2020-05-01 to 5/1/2020(month/date/year) in one line?

Comment: @ArpitFalcon you can do it in ``moment`` as follows: ``moment('2020-05-01').format('M/D/YYYY')``

Comment: `'2020-05-01'.replace((/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/g), (_, y, m, d) => [m, d, y].join('/'))`

Comment: of cause I forgot converting month and day into single digits where possible; one can make use of the "unary plus" operator and the above example changes to ... `'2020-05-01'.replace((/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/g), (_, y, m, d) => [+m, +d, y].join('/'))`

Answer (score 1):

```
const event = new Date('2020-05-01');
console.log((event.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + event.getDate() + "/" + event.getFullYear());
```

Comment: cheating ... its not in a single line ... ;-)

Comment: This is the right answer. Dates aren't strings, and treating them that will will just break later in unexpected ways.